# Running Loops with Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run driver.execute_script inside a loop to fetch some values during automation, however it appears that this method is not working. Just needed some help from bright minds how to get past this scenario. I am putting one sample code for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
cURL = "http://google.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(cURL)
for i in range(0, 3):
    print(i) ## To check if the code ran till here
    for x in range(0, 3):
        print(x) ## To check if the code ran till here
        script1 = "return document.URL"
        print(script1) ## To check if the code ran till here
        driver.execute_script(script1)
```

The output is as follows it runs the entire script barring driver.execute_script

> ```
> 0
> 0
> return document.URL
> 1
> return document.URL
> 2
> return document.URL
> 1
> 0
> return document.URL
> 1
> return document.URL
> 2
> return document.URL
> 2
> 0
> return document.URL
> 1
> return document.URL
> 2
> return document.URL
> ```

However if I only run the script in IPython Console

> In [11]:driver.execute_script(script1)

Output

> Out[11]: 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(driver.execute_script(script1))
```

It works